# how to download a pdf.php file from web browser using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to download a file named " view.pdf.php file from web browser and save it as pdf file.(file is obtained while clicking on print icon in web browser, it opens a .pdf.php file in another browser)

Tried some samples from stack over flow but unable to get that downloaded in correct format.

Code tried:

```
Declare Function URLDownloadToFile _
Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFileName As String) As Boolean
Dim lngRetVal As Long
lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFileName, 0, 0)
If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function
Sub Test()
DownloadFile "https://app.goscripts.com/vendor/viewreferral.php?Id=XXXXX", "\\test\test.pdf"

End Sub
```

when trying to open the downloaded file it shows as " Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open'test.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged" 
Please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: (1) Please [edit] your question and add exactly that code you already tried. (2) Probably something went wrong and there is no PDF inside the file you saved. Therefore open the file you downloaded in a pure text editor (eg. Notepad++) and check what it is inside? Is there a PDF inside then the file starts with `%PDF` in the first line. Or is there some HTML (eg. an error message)? It's probably hard to say anything about it without knowing the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your input!, yes while opening in text editor it contains HTML tag of website.

Comment: That shows that something went wrong with your download. Probably sent wrong header information or something. You need to figure that out, I cannot help you with that in particular as I don't know anything about that server.

Comment: Thanks for your time...

Comment: It looks like the server uses authentication, so I think without accessing the API of that server and handing over the credentials that won't work. Downloading a file with VBA is easy but downloading a file behind a username and password is cumbersome if you don't have access to the servers API. Even with access to it, it would be a good piece of work to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Located an alternate method to save the file from web browser,
Code:

```
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT = 0
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_SHOWHELP = 3
Const OLECMDID_SAVEAS = 4
Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2


Sub Sample()
Dim objIE, sh As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "https://123.com/vendor/vieworder.pdf.php?OrderId=XXXX"
objIE.Visible = True
Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_SAVEAS, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.AppActivate "Save AS"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
sh.SendKeys "done", 1
sh.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Thank for your support